# How to use fabric sdk to initialize the fabric CA

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am facing difficulty while initialising the fabric-sdk-go with fabric ca.

1. I am running the fabric CA server with default configuration, for that i using below code.

   when i use below code it will generate server config file with database.

   ```
   ./bin/fabric-ca-server start -b  admin:adminpwd --home ~/ca
   ```
2. Next i am using below code to enroll the admin, This will generated the admin yaml file in client side and keys.

   ```
   ./bin/fabric-ca-client enroll admin:adminpws localhost:7054
   ```

   I want to use https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/msp to create the client context.

   my question is

   which configuration file i need to load, to create the client context in fabric-sdk-go
   because i am trying to call

   ```
   func New(clientProvider context.ClientProvider, opts ...ClientOption) (*Client, error)
   ```

   it giving me error please suggest me

   ```
   failed to create msp client organization is not provided
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow my steps, NodeJS SDK

```
 const caEndPoint = "https://localhost:7054"
 const caName = "ca-org1"
 let tlsOptions = {
    trustedRoots: [],
    verify: false
  };
const fabricCAServices = require('fabric-ca-client');
const caService = new fabricCAServices(caEndPoint, tlsOptions, caName);
```

You can call available methods with caService

- enroll
- addAffiliation
- newIdentityService
- newCertificateService

To Register new Identity

```
const identityService = caService.newIdentityService();
    let registerObject = {
      enrollmentID: enrollmentId,
      type: type,
      affiliation: userOrg,
      maxEnrollments: maxEnrollments || 1,
      attrs: attributes,
      caname: caName
    }
const response = await identityService.create(registerObject, admin_user);
```

Comment: thanks for replay!, i am running in go, i am facing some issue related to fabric-sdk-go, where i need create the context, but i am not sure which configuration file i need to use to load/run fabric sdk. i am starting fabric ca server, its also create the fabric-ca-config.yaml do i need to load this configuration file to create the context or any other config file.